# Extract text using regular expression

Tags: ios, regex, matching, nsregularexpression

I'm trying to extract a case id from the string, Could someone help me with this

https://looney-tunes/review/case/CAAAAAAAAR-hw7QEAAAAMf___-A?caseGroup=12&queueId=52

I want to extract the portion after case/ and before '?'in the link. They're 27 characters in length.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
s='https://looney-tunes/review/case/CAAAAAAAAR-hw7QEAAAAMf___-A?caseGroup=12&queueId=52'
x=re.search("(?s)(?<=case/).*?(?=\\?)",s)
```

---

```
<re.Match object; span=(33, 60), match='CAAAAAAAAR-hw7QEAAAAMf___-A'>
```

In general, If you want a substring between two string
Use : `(?s)(?<=str1).*?(?=str2)`

as this was our `str2` -> `?`, had to escape it using `\\`

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid URL. The desired portion is the ***last path component***

- Swift

  ```
  let url = URL(string: "https://looney-tunes/review/case/CAAAAAAAAR-hw7QEAAAAMf___-A?caseGroup=12&queueId=52")!
  let caseID = url.lastPathComponent
  ```
- Objective-C

  ```
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://looney-tunes/review/case/CAAAAAAAAR-hw7QEAAAAMf___-A?caseGroup=12&queueId=52"];
  NSString *caseID = url.lastPathComponent;
  ```